# Plural or singular in these sentences

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Consider the following sentences:

- Prisons are the best options for serial killers
- Prisons are the best option for serial killers
- Prisons are a necessary evil
- Prisons are necessary evils

Are all these correct? Why/why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prisons are the best options for serial killers

Wrong in most cases. Unless you are talking about a specific set of prisons that you, or someone, gets to choose from, prisons are not separate options.  The concept of prisons, or the prison system (consisting of a collection of prisons) is a single option.

> Prisons are the best option for serial killers

This is ok because you are referring to the collection of all prisons as a singular object, but normally you would instead say "Prison is the best option for serial killers."

> Prisons are a necessary evil

Sounds ok even though it's probably not perfectly grammatical.  Again, normally you would use the singular case:  "Prison is a necessary evil." In the latter case, "prison" is treated more like a concept than a collection of buildings, which is more appropriate here.

> Prisons are necessary evils

This is fine but see my comment above for the more common usage.